# CastError (Null check operator used on a null value) FLUTTER ERROR using REST API

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-getx

I'm trying flutter and I'm newbie at this, I have a problem when I login with API SERVICE(im using Rest API  https://reqres.in), the login says

> _CastError (Null check operator used on a null value)

The error comes from source below

```
          Container(
              
              margin: const EdgeInsets.only(
                  left: 30, right: 30, top: 20, bottom: 20),
              padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 10),
              width: double.infinity,
              child: ElevatedButton(
                onPressed: () {
                 if (Loginvalues.loginFormKey.currentState!.validate()) {
                    Loginvalues.userLogin(Loginvalues.loginEmailController, Loginvalues.loginPasswordController,);
                 }
                },
                style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
                    backgroundColor: const Color(0xff84c148),
                    elevation: 5,
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.all(15),
                    shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15))),
                child: const SizedBox(
                  height: 15,

                  child: Text('SIGN IN',
                      style: TextStyle(
                        color: Colors.white,
                        fontSize: 15,
                        fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                      )),
                ),
              )),
```

At Line:

```dart
 onPressed: () {
   if (Loginvalues.loginFormKey.currentState!.validate()) { 
    Loginvalues.userLogin(Loginvalues.loginEmailController,  
    Loginvalues.loginPasswordController,);
```

This is my login controller dart where the loginFormkey was called:

```dart
// ignore_for_file: prefer_const_constructors

import 'dart:convert';
import 'package:get/get.dart';
import 'package:crud_sample/screens/home_page.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;

class LoginController with ChangeNotifier {
  TextEditingController loginEmailController = TextEditingController();
  TextEditingController loginPasswordController = TextEditingController();
  GlobalKey<FormState> loginFormKey = GlobalKey();

  userLogin(
    TextEditingController loginEmailController,
    TextEditingController loginPasswordController,
  ) async {
    try{
         var headers = {"Content-Type": "application/json"};
         var body = {
            'email' : loginEmailController.text.trim(),
            'password' : loginPasswordController.text.trim()
    };
    
       http.Response response = await http.post(
        Uri.parse('https://reqres.in/api/login'),
        headers: headers,
        body: jsonEncode(body),
        );
        
        if(response.statusCode == 200){
          Map json = jsonDecode(response.body.toString());
          print(json['token']);

          if(json['token'] != ''){
            Get.to(() => HomePage());
          }else{
            print("Invalid Details!");
          }
        }   
    }catch(e){
      print("Error $e");
    }
  }
}
```

My Dependencies

> cupertino_icons: ^1.0.2
> http: ^0.13.6
> get: ^4.6.5
> provider: ^6.0.5

Am I doing wrong?

Fix _CastError (Null check operator used on a null value)

Answer (score 0):

```
if (Loginvalues.loginFormKey.currentState != null &&) {
   if(Loginvalues.loginFormKey.currentState!.validate()){
    Loginvalues.userLogin(
      Loginvalues.loginEmailController,
      Loginvalues.loginPasswordController
    );
  }
  }
```

Change the following part with this. As it is giving error. Here you will first check if it is null. if not only then meet the condition and fulfill it. Hope this helps.

Edit:

```
if (Loginvalues.loginFormKey.currentState != null &&) {
   if(Loginvalues.loginFormKey.currentState!.validate()){
      Loginvalues.userLogin(
        Loginvalues.loginEmailController,
        Loginvalues.loginPasswordController,context
      );
    }
  }
```

Here send context with it. And on the other part:

```
if(json['token'] != ''){
        Navigator.push(
        context,
       MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => HomePage()),
   );
        }else{
         print("Invalid Details!");
       }
```

Receive the context.

Comment: I tried your's too the new problem is it doesn't navigate to Home page its just nothing.! I tried sending request from Postman the connection is working. But in Code nothing happens No navigation or error logs..

Comment: Posted new one. Hope this helps. If not let me know again.

Comment: Show which line causes exception in your code. In general, there's several ways to fix it: make variable nullable, check for null before you use ! operator or don't use ! operator and provide default value instead

Comment: I think the problem is the 'get' flutter plugin it doesnt show anything like [GET] route on console. I have get on my dependencies.

Comment: That is why I gave the solution with normal navigation and send context as parameter for other class to receive the context. Was this helpful?